# User location details from azure-ad-b2c User Journey Context Provider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We can can get the IPAddress of the user from User Journey Context Provider, but I need user location details. Is it possible to get the user location details ?

Answer (score 1):

All claims resolvers are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview

You cannot resolve their location/city etc. You can ask the user for their location instead:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Or resolve the IP to a location using your own REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-exchange?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: @jas-suri-msft has there been any change to this?

Comment: No changes to this